# Databricks Autoloader not saving data

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, databricks-autoloader

I am very new to Databricks `Autoloader`. I am trying to ingest a simple `csv` file with 3 records with the format [Fname, Lname, age].

The following code runs successfully in Databricks, but no data is getting saved. I'm sure I am missing something very basic. Can anyone please help where I may be going wrong.

```
df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles") \
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "failOnNewColumns") \
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/dbfs/FileStore/temp/schema/") \
  .load("/dbfs/FileStore/inbound/dsi/data/") \
  .writeStream.trigger(once=True) \
  .option("checkpointLocation","/dbfs/FileStore/temp/_checkpoint") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .start("/dbfs/FileStore/outbound/dsi/output/") \
  .awaitTermination()
```

The data is :
[image]

Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: How do you check for the new data? Also, you don't need `/dbfs` in the file names - it's only for the local file API

Comment: @AlexOtt the checkpoint provided by Autoloader determines if a file was read or not..

Comment: I know :-) I'm asking how did you check that you have no new data? looking into destination table?

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks for your reply. I was running the job manually in a notebook - when I called `df.show()` it did not show any records, although unprocessed files were present in the input directory.

Comment: df.show couldn’t be used for streams. Use display(df)

Comment: @marie20 did you solve this issue? It looks like I might have something similar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76287095/databricks-autoloader-works-on-compute-cluster-but-does-not-work-within-a-task